# Operations between rank 4 tensor and matrices - definitions and computations

Tags: matrices, tensors, trace

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a rank 4 tensor and $X$ be a rank 2 tensor (i.e. a matrix). Define the Frobenius inner product (FIP) of real matrices
$$
A : B = \operatorname{tr}(A^T B)
$$
A side question: if $A$ and $B$ are complex matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, then should we define the FIP as
$$A : B = \operatorname{tr}(A^H B)$$
where $(\cdot)^H = (\overline{\cdot})^T$ is conjugate transpose?

I am particulary interested in the following rank 4 isotrpoic tensor
$$
\mathcal{E}_{i,j,k,l} = \delta_{i,k}\delta_{j,l}, \qquad i,k=1,...,m, \quad j,l = 1,...,n
$$
(I know there is a more general form of this tensor, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589647/general-form-of-an-isotropic-fourth-rank-tensor/3976210)) and how it multiplies with matrices.

Let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{E} \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n \times m \times n}$ and $X, Y, A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ what are:

- $\mathcal{A} X = ?$
- $X \mathcal{A} Y^H = ?$
- $\mathcal{A} : X = ?$
- $\mathcal{A}^T = ?$ and $\mathcal{E}^T$? (if they are defined)

How they are defined, what tensor are they (e.g. what is their rank) and how they are calculated by components?

In particular, to prove:

- $ X = \mathcal{E} : X = X : \mathcal{E}$
- $ A X B = A \mathcal{E} B^H : X$

I would like to see definition both in general and by components (e.g. $(M \cdot P)_{ij} = \sum_k M_{ik} P_{kj}$).

This is related to this question: [Differentiating a column with respect to a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075738/differentiating-a-column-with-respect-to-a-matrix) but I think it is worth a specific question since this is quite general and can be useful to other tensor students.

**Edit:**
From the question linked above,
$$
\mathcal{A} X = \sum_l \mathcal{A}_{ijkl} X_{ln}
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{A} : X = \sum_k \sum_l \mathcal{A}_{ijkl} X_{kl}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The trace/Frobenius Product for *real* matrices is (as you've noted)
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
For *complex* matrices, you can stick with this definition or switch to the Inner Product
$$\langle A,B\rangle = {\rm Tr}(A^HB) \;\;\doteq\;\; A^*:B$$
I prefer the trace/Frobenius product because it has nicer alebraic properties

$\big({\rm where}\,\{\odot,\otimes\}$ denote Hadamard/Kronecker products$\big)$
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \quad&{\rm however}
  \quad \langle A,B\rangle\ne\langle B,A\rangle \\
(C\odot A):B &= C:(A\odot B)
  \quad&{\rm however}\quad 
  \langle C\odot A,B\rangle\ne\langle C,A\odot B\rangle \\
(A\otimes B):(X\otimes Y) &= (A:X)\otimes(B:Y)
  \quad&{\rm however}\quad 
  \langle A\otimes B,X\otimes Y\rangle\ne\langle A,X\rangle\otimes\langle B,Y\rangle \\\\
}$$
In terms of either product, the Frobenius Norm is very easy to compute
$$
\big\|A\big\|^2_F \;=\; A:A^* \;=\; \langle A,A\rangle \\
$$
Extending multiple dot products to higher-order tensors is straightforward.

For example, a quadruple-dot product would be
$$\eqalign{
{\cal P} &= {\cal A}::{\cal B} \\
{\cal P}_{ij....pq}
 &= \sum_k\sum_\ell\sum_m\sum_n
    {\cal A}_{ij..k\ell mn}{\cal B}_{k\ell mn..pq} \\
}$$
where the order of both $({\cal A,B})\ge 4$.

And once you become familiar with the Einstein convention, you can omit the $\Sigma$'s.

Comment: So the expressions I wrote above are correct?